# Finding number of occurrences for specific value

Tags: sql, filemaker

I'm trying to create a field (calculation result) in FileMaker Pro 13 that will return the number of times a specific value is selected in a specific field.

For Example:

Say you have Table 1. Table 1 only has 1 field named Field 1. Field 1 is a drop down list field with the options "A","B", & "C". The following data is from the records of Table 1 using the field, Field 1:

Record 1: Table 1::Field 1 = "A"

Record 2: Table 1::Field 1 = "A"

Record 3: Table 1::Field 1 = "B"

Record 4: Table 1::Field 1 = "C"

What I want is a counter that searches across the records for table one and finds how many times a certain option is selected. For example, I want to know how many times "A" was selected in Field 1 and it would return "2".

What I have tried to do so far is the following  but it hasn't worked out so hot (returns "?"):

ExecuteSQL(

"SELECT Field 1

FROM Table 1

WHERE Field 1 = 'A'"

;"";"")

Any suggestions for a correct SQL script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct version of your Execute

```
ExecuteSQL(

"SELECT Count(\"Field 1\")

FROM \"Table 1\"

WHERE \"Field 1\" = ?"

;"";"";"A")
```

When you use ExecuteSQL, you're passing a string into FileMaker's function and then behind the scenes FileMaker uses that string and the various other pieces you give it to perform the action.

If you have a space in your field or table name, e.g. `Field 1`, FileMaker thinks you mean "Select a field name `Field` and a field named `1`. You need to quote the field name if it contains spaces or special characters, but you can't use just regular double quotes because that would end the string.

The way to fix it is what I did above; escape the double quotes around the field or table name.

Also, the `?` and the `"A"` at the bottom allows you to pass data into the query, i.e. parameterizing the query. This means you could do a loop where each iteration of the loop you pass in a different value where I have `"A"`. E.g. You could do this:

```
ExecuteSQL(

"SELECT Count(\"Field 1\")

FROM \"Table 1\"

WHERE \"Field 1\" = ?"

;"";""; Table 1::Search Field)
```

or

```
ExecuteSQL(

"SELECT Count(\"Field 1\")

FROM \"Table 1\"

WHERE \"Field 1\" = ?"

;"";"";$searchValue)
```

Be careful though, ExecuteSQL doesn't cache records that it pulls if you're in a server/client environment so this calculation could get pretty sluggish if you have a lot of records in the table, you're going over the wan, or both. I would suggest trying to get the count a different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*) from Table1 where Field1='A'
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for some reason. Returned: "?"